# play-games-plugin-for-unity - show specific Leaderboard

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I'm trying to integrate the google play Leaderboard with help of the [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) plugin into my game.
It works fine, committing to Leaderboard an all, only one thing is not working. When I call the Leaderboard

```
    //LEADERBOARD
    if (GUI.Button(leaderboardButton, "Leaderboard"))
    {
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).ShowLeaderboardUI(Constants.LEADERBOARDID);

        // Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();
    }
```

it opens the window where I see **all** leaderboards. But I'm giving a specific id. This would be the behaviour I expect from the line Social.ShowLeaderboardUI(); which is commented out. The overload with a given Id (hid behind Constants.LEADERBOARDID) should start the specific Leaderboard UI according to the doc. Someone knows if this is an issue (haven't seen any report on GitHub) and how to solve it? It isn't that that big of an issue, but one click is better than two.

I tried something interesting. I changed the Id to some wrong value. Still the same behavior (opening the window with all leaderboards). Of course committing the score doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, i found the error in the sourcecode of the Plugin, fixed it and resolved the problem. So here I present the fix if someone needs it. It's in the LeaderboardManager class.

This is how ShowUI is called:

```
internal void ShowUI(string leaderboardId, Action callback) {
Misc.CheckNotNull(callback);

    C.LeaderboardManager_ShowAllUI(mServices.AsHandle(), Callbacks.InternalShowUICallback,
        Callbacks.ToIntPtr(callback));
}
```

This should be the correct version

```
internal void ShowUI(string leaderboardId, Action callback) {
Misc.CheckNotNull(callback);

    C.LeaderboardManager_ShowUI(mServices.AsHandle(),leaderboardId, Callbacks.InternalShowUICallback,
        Callbacks.ToIntPtr(callback));
}
}
```

See the difference? C.LeaderboardManager_Show**All**UI instead of C.LeaderboardManager_ShowUI is called.

Comment: This appears to have since been fixed in the plugin.

Comment: Yes I got in contact with the developer and fixed it.